# If $m$ is a measure, then is it also true that $m(E) = \inf\{\sum\limits_k |I_k|\}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove that measure is countable subadditive (with respect to nondisjoint union)

> $m(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_K) \leq \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty m(E_k)$

My question **is it true** that:

> $m(E) = \inf\{\sum\limits_k |I_k||\{I_k\}  \text{ covers } E\}$ where
>   $m$ is a measure

I am asking because the proof of

> $m^*(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_K) \leq \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty m^*(E_k)$
>   directly follows from $m^*(E) = \inf\{\sum\limits_k |I_k||\{I_k\}  \text{ covers } E\}$

I am a little bit confused if I should approach this similarly to the proof involving outer measure, or some other way without involving any covering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true for any measure that $m(E) = \inf \{\sum |I_k|\}$ where the inf is over sequences of intervals that cover $E$. It is true for Lebesgue measure, but not an arbitrary measure. The way to prove subadditivity is by disjointifying your cover.
Let $E_k$ be measurable and $E$ be their union. Define $F_k = E_k \setminus \cup_{i=1}^{k-1} E_i$. Then the $F_k$ are disjoint but still union to $E$, and hence
$$
m(\cup_k E_k) = m(E) = m(\cup_k F_k) = \sum_k m(F_k) \leq \sum_k m(E_k)
$$
where in the last step we used that $F_k \subseteq E_k$.

Comment: Is there a easy way to see that $F_k = E_k \setminus \cup_{i=1}^{k-1} E_i$ should be disjoint given that $F_k \cap F_{k-1} =  E_k \setminus \cup_{i=1}^{k-1} E_i \cap  E_{k-1} \setminus \cup_{i=1}^{k-2} E_i$ is kind of hard to evaluate

Comment: By definition $F_k\subseteq E_k$. If $k < k'$ then it cannot be that $F_k \cap  F_{k'} \neq \emptyset$. Any element in the intersection must be in $E_k$, but $F_{k'} = E_{k'} \setminus \cup_{i=1}^{k'-1} E_i$ has by definition removed all elements of $E_k$ since $k < k'$. Thus $F_k \cap F_{k'} = \emptyset$.